# Is there a way to create an iterable list from a string?

Tags: templates, kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I'm passing the following string through values.yaml:

```
urls: http://example.com http://example2.com http://example3.com
```

Is there a way to create a list from this, so i can then do something like:

```
{{ range $urls }}
{{ . }}
{{ end }}
```

The problem is I'm passing the urls var in a dynamic fashion, and I'm also can't avoid using a single string for that (ArgoCD ApplicationSet wont let me pass a list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically all you need is just add this line in your template `yaml`:

```
{{- $urls := splitList " " .Values.urls }}
```

It will import `urls` string from `values.yaml` [as the list](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/string_slice.html) so you will be able run your code which you posted in your question.

**Simple example based on [helm docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/)**:

1. Let's get simple chart used in [helm docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/getting_started/) and prepare it:

   ```
   helm create mychart
   rm -rf mychart/templates/*
   ```
2. Edit `values.yaml` and insert `urls` string:

   ```
   urls: http://example.com http://example2.com http://example3.com
   ```
3. Create ConfigMap in `templates` folder (name it `configmap.yaml`)

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: ConfigMap
   metadata:
     name: {{ .Release.Name }}-configmap
   data:
     {{- $urls := splitList " " .Values.urls }}
     urls: |- 
       {{- range $urls }}
       - {{ . }}
       {{- end }}
   ```

   As can see, I'm using your loop (with "- " to avoid creating empty lines).
4. Install chart and check it:

   ```
   helm install example ./mychart/
   helm get manifest example
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   ---
   # Source: mychart/templates/configmap.yaml
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: ConfigMap
   metadata:
     name: example-configmap
   data:
     urls: |-
       - http://example.com
       - http://example2.com
       - http://example3.com
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Split by spaces to get an array of urls.

```
{{- range _, $v := $urls | split " " }}
{{ $v }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: `splitList` should be preferred over `split` for the following reason: `split` produces a dictionary with looks like this: `{"_0":"v0","_1":"v1","_10":"v10","_11":"v11","_2":"v2",...}` - in particular the ordering of lists bigger than 10 items is going to be wrong.